# Deleting data in pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have a pickle db with 5 variable in it that goes : `rafTur, rafKat, rafNo, rafIndex, rafIndexData`. I'm trying to delete a data inside my pickle file. My main goal is taking an input from user that goes like [this](https://prnt.sc/114pq3y) :

- rafTur = S rafKat = 1 rafNo = 2 rafIndex = 3

And then finding that imput from my pickle file that named `noSqlDB`. and then delete the entire data about input.

```
def delPic():
    infile = open('noSqlDB', 'rb+')
    sistem = pickle.load(infile)
    flag = False

    rafTur = str(input('Rafın türünü giriniz : '))
    rafKat = int(input('Rafın katını giriniz : '))
    rafNo = int(input('Rafın Nosunu giriniz : '))
    rafIndex = int(input('Rafın indexini giriniz : '))

    # read to the end of file.
    for x in range((len(sistem) + 1)):
        try:

            if (sistem['rafTur'].upper() == rafTur.upper() and sistem['rafKat'] == rafKat and sistem['rafNo'] == rafNo and sistem['rafIndex'] == rafIndex):

                del sistem
                flag = True

            sistem = pickle.load(infile)
        except EOFError:
            break

    if flag == False:
        print('Record not Found')

    infile.close()
```

When i run this code nothing changes. The data stays on `noSqlDB`. How can i delete the data inside the `noSqlDB` ? [like this](https://prnt.sc/114r05d)

I tried changing

```
del sistem
```

to

```
del sistem['rafTur'],sistem['rafKat'], sistem['rafNo'],sistem['rafIndex'],sistem['rafIndexData']
```

Comment: You never write to your pickle file again, why do you *expect* it to change?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So deleting doesn't enough i should write to file ok i'll try.

Comment: What do you mean "deleting"? `del sistem` deletes the *variable*, but even if it did delete *the object* that wouldn't affect your pickle... *why would it*? Note, `del sistem` does nothing useful, because you overwrite `sistem = pickle.load(infile)` *anyway*

Comment: [This](https://prnt.sc/114r05d) is what i mean by deleting. And i don't know how to do it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def unpickle_database(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                yield pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                break

def save_object(obj, filename,a):

    if a < 1:
        with open(filename, 'wb+') as output:
            pickle.dump(obj, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    else :
        with open(filename, 'ab+') as output:
            pickle.dump(obj, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


def delPic():

    temp =0
    students = list(unpickle_database('noSqlDB'))

    for student in students:
        print(student)
        save_object(student, 'noSqlDB',temp)
        temp += 1
```

Found a solution after trying some code here it is.